# XML Schema to match the following ("all", with unbounded maxOccurs?)

Tags: xsd

Say I have an element, call it `<A>`.  `<A>` can have children types of `<B>` and `<C>`.  Now - here's the twist.  Any number of `<B>` and `<C>` children can live in `<A>`, in any order.

For example:

```
<A>
  <C>
  <C>
  <B>
  <C>
  <B>
  <B>
  <C>
  ...
</A>
```

Is there a schema rule that fits this?  Seems like "all" would work, if I could put maxOccurs="unbounded", but I guess that's not legal.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Answering my own question -- looks like trang (http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) gave me the anwer:

```
<xs:element name="A">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="B"/>
      <xs:element ref="C"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Very cool!

Comment: Helpful, thanks.  Any idea if it's possible to do something similar that will enforce the existence of at least one <B> and at least one <C> while allowing any number of each, in any order?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root" type="root"/>
  <xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="a"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This schema validates

```
<root>
</root>
```

But if you omit `minOccurs="0"` of `<xs:choice>`, it does not.

It validates

```
<root>
  <a/>
</root>
```

without `minOccurs="0"`.

Comment: Your answer might be right but is not working code. Please improve your answer to working "copy/paste" code by editing your answer yourself.

Comment: What I meant.... make it a working answer... similar to that user desau show with his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827606/8928024). Anyone who doesn't have as much as experience as you do...will not grasp it directly. So it should be "idiot" proof answer with enough context.

Comment: embed the freeformatter link into your answer... it improves the quality of your answer. And remove comment afterwards... which I'll do with this as well.